# React Native point Animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-native-animatable

[image]

> I just need to create an animated progress bar which is exactly same as above picture. I have created an arc bar. But I'm struggling with white point move animation. How can I make a point movement from Right to left?

Here I used - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package for creating slider as you want https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider

Comment: This one is awesome. can I make it as little bit arc as same as in the picture?

Comment: there are properties you can check that, you can give style to it also.